# Manage error ng-if angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a form with a select option. If the value is yes I show up a div. When I validate my form the  doesn't appear.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.backendIntegrationUrl, 'has-success': valid.backendIntegrationUrl}">
          <label for="backendIntegrationUrl">backend service URL *</label>
          <input type="text" name="backendIntegrationUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="example: https://qualif.myapi.com/myapi/v1 " ng-model="api.backendIntegrationUrl"  ng-required="true">
          <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.backendIntegrationUrl.required">backend service URL is required.</span>            
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="basicAuth">
          <label for="basicAuth">basic auth info</label>
          <select name="basicAuth" class="form-control" ng-init="api.basicAuth = api.basicAuth || 'no'" ng-model="api.basicAuth" id="basicAuth" >
              <option value="no">no</option>
              <option value="yes">yes</option>
          </select>
        </div>                               
     </div>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-if="api.basicAuth == 'yes'" id="yesAuth">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendUsername, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendUsername}">
           <div class="form-group" >
               <label for="basicAuthForBackendUsername">basic auth username *</label>
               <input type="text" id="basicAuthForBackendUsername" name="basicAuthForBackendUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth username" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendUsername" ng-required="api.basicAuth =='yes'"> 
               <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendUsername.required">basic auth username is required.</span>       
           </div>                                
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendPassword, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendPassword}">
           <div class="form-group" >
               <label for="basicAuthForBackendPassword">basic auth password *</label>
               <input type="text" id="basicAuthForBackendPassword" name="basicAuthForBackendPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth password" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendPassword" ng-required="api.basicAuth =='yes'"> 
               <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendPassword.required">basic auth password is required.</span>       
           </div>                                
        </div>
 </div>
```

I have a validate function that validate or not the form like that:

```
$scope.help = {};
$scope.invalid = {};
$scope.invalid.version = $scope.userForm.version.$invalid;
```

It's the same for valid.

How can I solve my problem to appear the  with no value also?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please check `api.basicAuth1` is undefined or not?

And you should be declare `api.basicAuth` globally on your controller.

sample looks like:

```
function controllername($scope)
{
 $scope.api = { basicAuth: "Yes" }
     .
     .
     .
     .
     // other codes
     .
     .
     .
     .
}
```